# Session expire or invalid session

Tags: integration

I am getting

> Session invalid or session expires

error when i am calling one Saleforce org from another Salesforce org.
here my code for callout.

```
String content = '{"Name": "Some acoount", "Phone":"9742882954"}';
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accountacc');
 req.setMethod('POST');

 String username = 'sarvesh01@gmail.com';
 String password = 'parvati@3';

 Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
 String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
 EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
 req.SetBody(content);
 req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
 req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
 req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());    
 Http http = new Http();
 HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
 System.debug(res.getBody());
```

my rest class in another salesforce org.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accountacc/*')  
global with sharing class callAccount {  

@HttpPost  
 global static String doPost() {  

 RestRequest request = RestContext.request;  
 RestResponse response = RestContext.response;  
 String jSONRequestBody=request.requestBody.toString().trim();  
 Account accObj = (Account)JSON.deserializeStrict(jSONRequestBody,Account.class);  
 insert accObj;  
 return accObj.Id;  
}  
@HttpGet  
global static Account doGet() {  

 RestRequest request = RestContext.request;  
 RestResponse response = RestContext.response;  
 String accountId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);  
 Account acc= [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];  
 return acc;  
}  
}
```

Can any one help me out please........
Thanks,
sarvesh.

Comment: Can you try with authorization type 'Bearer' instead of 'OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not support basic authentication for REST calls.

Probably the most appropriate authentication to use is [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm) where a certificate is used to secure the Salesforce to Salesforce access. See [An Apex implementation of the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/an-apex-implementation-of-the-oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow/) for how to make the request in Apex.

Once the access token is obtained it can be used to authenticate the REST requests:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + accessToken);
...
```

Comment: Hi Keith C,  Thanks for your replay but can you give example for  salesforce  rest callout

Comment: @sarvesh Added to the answer.